# Spivak's definition of a $k$-dimensional mainfold

Tags: differential-geometry, elementary-set-theory, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

In Calculus on Manifolds Spivak gives the following definition of a manifold:
[image]

But $\Bbb{R}^k \times \{0\}$ is a set of $(k+1)$-tuples and $V$ is a set of $n$-tuples, so
$$V \cap (\Bbb{R}^k \times \{0\}) = \emptyset $$ if $k+1 \neq n$. This doesn't add up with what Spivak states it's equal to.

Shouldn't it be $\Bbb{R}^k \times \{0\}^{n - k}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here in the expression $\mathbb R^k \times \{0\}$ the symbol $0$ denotes the zero vector in $\mathbb R^{n-k}$. Often the same symbol $0$ is used to mean different things. The description $\{ y \in V \mid y^{k+1} = \cdots = y^n = 0 \}$ might be more clear.

Comment: "The vector $(0,\dotsc,0)$ will usually be denoted simply $0$." is stated on p.3 of the book.

Comment: Thank you. But I find this to be a pretty sloppy definition since tuples of different dimensions are not the same and there is no way to denote the dimension in this notation